# What's the best way to deal with IE's disappearing scrollbar overylaying content?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I [have a site](http://strugee.net) that has a button in the bottom-right corner. Everything works, but in Internet Explorer (10), the button gets overlayed with the scrollbar when the user moves the cursor.

The solution is obviously a bit of padding, but I'm wondering what the best way to do this is, especially since apparently after IE 10, conditional comments are disabled in standards mode.

Per @Teemu's suggestion in the comments, I've tried using `<span>` tags instead of `<i>` tags. No luck: the page is the exact same.

Comment: @Teemu why would the margins be causing the problem? the fix is margins/padding. the problem is IE's scrollbar. plus, the `<i>` tag _does_ have a closing tag.

Comment: You need literal `</i>` after `<i>` ("`Tag omission: None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.`") Italic style font has always caused a "margin-right" problem in IEs. The simplest solution would be to use some other element for this.

Comment: @Teemu **the code does have a literal `</i>`**. it is, literally, `<i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>`.

Comment: Strange, when I look at the source with IE10's devtools, I see `<i class="icon-lightbulb"/>`, but other browsers show `<i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>`. Anyway, that's not the actual problem, have you tried `span` instead of `i`?

Comment: @Teemu no such luck. FWIW, [here's the source](https://github.com/strugee/strugee.github.com/).